# Best practice for the keyword this in a module defined using object literal notation?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have defined a module using object literal notation as follows:

```
   var myModule = {
                myProperty: "someValue",
                myConfig: {
                       useCaching: true,
                       language: "en"
                },
                saySomething: function () {
                       console.log( "XXX" );
                },

                functionA: function () {
                       // do something
                ),
                functionB: function () {
                      // need call functionA
                     myModule.functionB();  // style 1
                     this.functionB();      // style 2
                )
    };
```

What's the purpose using keyword this, what's the difference between style 1 & 2.
I also noticed some people use `var that = this`, and then that.`func()` , how is this better? And where should I put the `var that = this`, in my module.

What's the best practice for object literal notation?

Comment: You've got some serious typos in that code.

Comment: If you change the module name, you will need to replace all instances of the name in style 1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the value of `this` depends on what you call the method on. When you do `myModule.func()`, `this` inside `func` will be `myModule`. When you do more complicated things like:

```
function delegator(func) {
  func();
}

delegator(myModule.functionB);
```

..., you will notice that `this` inside `func` will no longer refer to `myModule`, but will instead be the global object (or `undefined` if you're using strict mode).

That is the reason people alias `that` to `this`. In your scenario, there is no place where you can put that alias, because you're defining an object.

It's safe to use `this` when you know the method will always be called on your module, otherwise you should use the `myModule.functionB()` approach.

Comment: So in my scenario, i can only do `myModule.functionA()`?